# Getting TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function after upgrading Node to latest - 9.3.0

Tags: node.js, gulp

Just in case anyone else encounters this.  I searched and didn't find a duplicate in here. Apologies if there is one.

OS X Sierra 10.12.6

Getting this error when running Gulp after upgrading Node:

`TypeError: require.extensions.hasOwnProperty is not a function`

My prior Node version was 6.x ( before v8 )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ran this:

```
rm -r node_modules/require-dir ( not sure if this is really needed )
```

then:

```
npm uninstall && npm-check-updates -g && npm install npm-check-updates -g
```

then got this error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'require-dir'
```

then ran this:

```
npm install require-dir
```

Problem Solved